# Increasing Numerical Values by Increments

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, increment

I have the following code where my life would be made significantly easier if a sed/awk command or something like it could be applied to increment select strings of numerical values below:

```
wgrib2 gfsf_00.grib2 -s | egrep '(:SNOM:surface)' | wgrib2 -i gfsf_00.grib2 -grib gfsconvf_00.grib2

wgrib2 gfsf_03.grib2 -s | egrep '(:SNOM:surface)' | wgrib2 -i gfsf_03.grib2 -grib gfsconvf_03.grib2

wgrib2 gfsf_06.grib2 -s | egrep '(:SNOM:surface)' | wgrib2 -i gfsf_06.grib2 -grib gfsconvf_06.grib2
```

The model frames increase by three, hence the 00, 03, and 06 frames. As there are hundreds of frames processed every day by various weather models, it would be greatly appreciated if there was a way to change the sequence of numbers from 00, 03, and 06 in the code above to (and this would process the next three model files in succession), 09, 12, and 15.

The next model hours to be processed are 18, 21, and 24 (as you might have guessed)..

Thank you to all that help on helping me with this issue in advance.

Comment: Are you certain this question is related to the Python programming language?

Comment: @gragas - I know in a somewhat related question I asked earlier, there was a solution provided in python.

Comment: Bash has loops (http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html) and functions (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/complexfunct.html) . I feel like adding python is just making things more complicated than they should be

Comment: @NightShadeQueen - I figured that would be the case, I'll remove the tag.

Comment: Might want to add in a tag for bash/zsh/sh/whatever shell-scripting thing you're using

Comment: Well in bash running echo gfsconvf_00.grib2|sed -e 's/00/09/' results in gfsconvf_09.grib2.  That's the sed s or substitute command.

Comment: @TrisNefzger - How would that be applied to change the code in the fie I have from 00 to 09? If possible, how would that always increase the number by three every time that code is ran? So, the first time, gfsconvf_00.grib2 becomes gfsconvf_03.grib2 and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am putting this in an answer since it is too long for a comment:

To change them in a file what I would do is write a python or ruby script to open the file read only, then search each line in it for gfsconvf_(\d\d).grib2 using regex matching where \d matches a single integer digit and the parentheses () capture it in a variable $1, then set new_num = ($1 + 3) % 24 (that's mod 24 so it rolls over at midnight assuming that is what you want), then format newNum as a string with a leading zero if necessary and replace the entire match with gfsconvf_newNumAsString.grib2 and write the line to a new file.  Then if necessary, the old file can be renamed or removed and the new file can be given the name of the original file. It would be best to keep the original file around for a while in case its needed for inspection or recovery.  At this point I am not sure what are the exact requirements about what needs to be replaced, for example maybe the 00 in gfsf_00.grib2 needs to be updated also, and the time rolloever requirements have not been stated either.